# Is it possible to put this function only at that element where I´m clicking into the text field

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
$('.parent > *')
    .focus(function() {
        $('.parent').addClass('focused');
    })
    .blur(function() {
        $('.parent').removeClass('focused');
    });
```

```css
.parent {background: green}
.focused {background: red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
    <input class="childInput" type="text" />
    <div class="sibling"></div>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="parent">
    <input class="childInput" type="text" />
    <div class="sibling"></div>
</div>
```

So is it possible that only the background-color change where i´m clicking in ?

Answer (score 2):

This will identify *every* matching element:

```
$('.parent').addClass('focused');
```

So basically every element with the `parent` class.  Instead, you want just the *closest* matching element:

```
$(this).closest('.parent').addClass('focused');
```

Answer (score 2):

You must select the parent of the clicked children instead of select all elements with the class `.parent`.

```
$('.parent > *')
    .focus(function() {
        $(this).closest('.parent').addClass('focused');
    })
    .blur(function() {
        $(this).closest('.parent').removeClass('focused');
    });
```

The part `$(this).closest('.parent')` inside the event handlers take the click element `this` and select the closest `.parent`.

This is the documentation of `.closest`: https://api.jquery.com/closest/

Answer (score 0):

```
You have to select each element parent. So you have to use this selector for select a particular element.

$('.parent > *')
    .focus(function() {
        $(this).parent('.parent').addClass('focused');
    })
    .blur(function() {
        $(this).parent('.parent').removeClass('focused');
    });
</script>
```